# Some basic Topological proof help please.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

Basically im really bad at proofs and i havent done math in almost a year and decided id like to learn topology on my own... just want someone to be really critical on my solutions please also i would really like to see this question solved directly ( the part below where im trying to use $ B(r,a)|r>0$ id really like to be able to solve the entire question in this kind of direct way)

Q1i) Prove that for any set A in a topological space we have 
$\partial \overline A \subset \partial A$ and $\partial (Int A) \subset \partial A$

My Line of thought any set A that is open $\partial \overline A = \partial A$ and for any set A that is closed $\partial \overline A = \partial A$

If A is Open then $\partial (Int A) = \partial A$ same should be true if A is closed

There may need to be some clarification the null set and $\mathbb {R^{n}}$ where $n \in \mathbb {Z}$ as they are both open and closed so ill start with these two.

Where A = nullset the $\overline A$ = nullset since $\overline A \subset A$ and $ A \subset \overline A$ thus $\partial \overline A = \partial A$ and $\partial (Int A) = \partial A$ as the null set is open A= Int A = nullset.

When A = $\mathbb {R^{n}}$ where $n \in \mathbb {Z}$ since $\overline A \backslash  A =\partial A$= nullset. Since we know that $\partial A =$ nullset we know $ \overline A = A$

The Int A =A

Proof  $\forall x\in A $ $ \exists B(r,x)|r>0 $ <- im sure that such a direct aproach should work i know this is true because A is open and that should tell me somehow that $\exists$ an open Neighborhood $\forall x\in A$ and that by definition shows that all $x\in A$ are interior points.

Lastly for a set A that is neither open or closed $A \subset \overline A$

Since A is not open $ \exists a \in A $ where $ \forall B(r,a)| r>0 $  not one of these B(r,a) can contain only points in A  hence $\exists$ at least one point $a\in A$ with no open neighborhood.

we also know that for every  $a \in A$ that their does not exists an open neighborhood that $ a \in \overline A$ we also know by  the definition of a boundary point that for all a that this is true for $a\in \partial A$

now there are two possibilities eithier $\forall a \in A$ that their is no open neighborhood for there also is no open neighborhood for them in $\overline A$ or that $\exists$ at least one $ a \in A$ with no open neighborhood in A  that now has an open neighborhood in $\overline A$

When the first is true $\partial \overline A = \partial A$ as all boundary points in A are also boundary points in $\overline A$

if the second is true $\exists $ at least one boundary point $a \in A$ such that $a\in \{ \overline A $ \ $ \partial \overline A \} = Int \overline A$ hence there is at least one point $a\in \partial A$ such that $a\notin \partial \overline A$ using above $ \partial A $ \ $\{$all elements a that this is true for$\} =  \partial \overline A $

Since $\forall x \in \partial \overline A$ it is true that $x \in \partial A$ and that  $\exists a\in \partial A$ such that $a\notin \partial \overline A$ we know by definition that $\partial \overline A \subset \partial A$

Lastly $\partial (Int A) \subset \partial A$ when A is not Open or closed.

I feel like the answer is already there i just can't put the words together right.. i feel like the fact that the $\overline {Int \space A} =  \overline A$ Which easily implies $\overline {Int \space A} \backslash \partial {Int \space A}  = \overline A \backslash \partial A$ so $\partial (Int A) = \partial A$ as long as no boundary point of A becomes an interior points of $\overline A$ if it does then that point which ill call y... will be $y\in \partial A$ but $y\notin \partial Int \space A$ so eithier they have the same points or $\partial A$ has more ( a finite or infinite number more)

Q1ii) give an example where all three of these sets are diffrent.
Im assuming it means these three. $\partial \overline A$, $ \partial A$ and $\partial (Int A) $

Let $A=\{ x|x\in \{ [-1,0)\cup [0,1]\}$ for some reason once i right that down it seems wrong i want it to be a set where its dense on boths side of a point but to not include the point on one side so theres no open neighborhood around that point if that makes sense?

Comment: Note that $B(r,x)$ only makes sense in a metric space, not in a general topological space.